# convert 24 hours into 12 hours

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

i have ionic code that load times for me but it make it 24 hours and i want it in 12 hours with AM or PM

i tried many things but not work

this is my code

```
loadTimes() {
    this.availabilityTimes = new Array<Array<string>>();
    for(let i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        this.availabilityTimes.push(new Array<string>());
    }
    let date = new Date();
    for (let avail of this.availabilities) {
        let dateStart = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), Number(avail.start.split(':')[0]), Number(avail.start.split(':')[1]), 0);
        let dateEnd = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), Number(avail.end.split(':')[0]), Number(avail.end.split(':')[1]), 0);

        let availabilityTime = new Array<string>();
        let time: number = dateStart.getTime();
        while(time <= dateEnd.getTime()) {
            let dateIn = new Date(time);
            availabilityTime.push((dateIn.getHours()<10?('0'+dateIn.getHours()):String(dateIn.getHours())) +':'+ (dateIn.getMinutes()<10?('0'+dateIn.getMinutes()):String(dateIn.getMinutes())) +':00');
            time = time + 3600000;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all and i got the answer and here what i did for any one who need it

first install the moment

the i create pipe by : ionic g pipe MyPipe

then i add this code in the MyPipe file

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

/**
 * Generated class for the MyPipe pipe.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html for more info on
 * Angular Pipes.
 */
@Pipe({
  name: 'my',
})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(time: any): any {
    let hour = (time.split(':'))[0]
    let min = (time.split(':'))[1]
    let part = hour > 12 ? 'م' : 'ص';
    min = (min+'').length == 1 ? `0${min}` : min;
    hour = hour > 12 ? hour - 12 : hour;
    hour = (hour+'').length == 1 ? `0${hour}` : hour;
    return `${hour}:${min} ${part}`
  }
}
```

after that in app.mdoule.ts file you have to add MyPipe under the declarations and providers

and last things is in your code add this in .ts file in constructor

```
private MyPipe:MyPipe
```

and in .html file

it will be like this

```
{{time |my: "hh:mm:ss"}}
```

## MyPipe and my => you must change it by the name that you want when you generate the pipe

Comment: Maybe you should use a more explicit name for your pipe. "my" is not really meaningful

Answer (score 3):

Get date as string format, split to parts.

```
hours = hours % 12 + (hours < 13 ? ' AM' : ' PM');
```

join

Answer (score 1):

You must use pipe for reusability. Create new typescript pipe with below code

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({
   name: 'dateTime'
})

export class DateTimePipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(value: any, format: string = ''): string {
       // Try and parse the passed value.
       const momentDate = moment(value);

       // If moment didn't understand the value, return it unformatted.
       if (!momentDate.isValid()) return value;

       // Otherwise, return the date formatted as requested.
       return momentDate.format(format);
   }
}
```

and in HTML use this pipe

```
<td>{{YourDateField.Date |dateTime :'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A'}}</td>
```

Comment: i cant import moment

Comment: npm install --save moment

Comment: i got this error 

The pipe 'dateTime' could not be found (""selectedTime(time)">
                    <ion-card>
                        <span class="center">{{[ERROR ->]time |dateTime :'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A' }}</span>
                    </ion-card>
                </i"): ng:///AppModule/Appointment_BookPage.html@22:47

Comment: i have problem i did all this but no thing change i think the problem is from the pipe code

Comment: Why can't you import moment ?